# Segmentation fault after scanf on array passed to function

Tags: c

I'm trying to finish a workshop but I'm getting a segmentation fault after I call inputVector function in the if statement. I have no idea why it's giving me an error. There are no warnings at compile time and the testing on the array passed actually displays what was recorded. I'm running OSX Maverick but I also tested on a linux system to no avail. If someone could shine a light on this I'd really appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "matrix.h"

int main() {

    int row = 0 , col = 0, option = 0;
    int vector[9], result[9];
    int matrix[9][9];

    do{
        printf("Number of rows (0 to exit) ? ");
        scanf("%d", &row);
        if(row != 0) {
            printf("Number of columns          ? ");
            scanf("%d", &col);

            inputMatrix(row, col, matrix);

            printf("Pre (0) or Post (1) Multiply ? ");
            scanf("%d", &option);

            if(option == 0){
                inputVector(row, vector);
                printf("TESTING 1");
                preMulti(row, col, matrix, vector, result);
                printf("TESTING 2");
                display(col, result);
            }
            else if(option == 1){ 
                inputVector(col, vector);
                postMulti(row, col, matrix, vector, result);
                display(row, result);
            }

            return 0;       
        }// END IF
    } while( row != 0 );// End While

} // End Main
```

#### matrix.cpp

```
#include "matrix.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void inputMatrix(int row , int col, int matrix[][MAXCOL]) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        printf("Row %d ? ", i + 1);
        for ( int k = 0; k < col; k++)
            scanf("%d", &matrix[i][k]);
    }
}
void inputVector(int size, int vector[]) {
    printf("Vector? ");
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        scanf("%d" , &vector[i]);
        printf(" Recorded %d \n", vector[i]);
    }
    printf("TESTING 3");
}

void preMulti(int row, int col, int matrix[][MAXCOL], int vector[], int result[]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++ ) {
        result[i] = 0;
        for( int k = 0; k < row; i++) 
            result[i] += vector[k] * matrix[k][i];
    }
}
void postMulti(int row, int col, int matrix[][MAXCOL], int vector[], int result[]) {
    for( int i = 0; i < row; i++ ) {
        result[i] = 0;
        for( int k = 0; k < col; i++) 
            result[i] += vector[k] * matrix[i][k];
    }
}

void display(int size, int vector[]) {
    printf("Result: ");
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", vector[i]);
}
```

Comment: Debuggers are a pretty good tool for dealing with segfaults.

Comment: What did gdb tell you? What did valgrind tell you?

Comment: It would be an improvement _not_ to name your int array _vector_, as `vector` has special significance in C++.  It is almost as confusing as if you were nameing a `struct` _Struct_

Comment: Is this C code or C++ code? What input did you give the program?

Comment: Try changing the prototype for `inputVector` parameter 3 from `int vec[]` to `int *vec`.  I once had a bug that came from that, but I can't remember the exact situation.  Background info on pointers and arrays [here](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~myers/c++/notes/pointers2.html) in case it helps.

Comment: @David - Judging from "   // MATRIX.CPP", it is intended as C++, but hard to tell from the syntax, i.e. it appears to be ANSI (ISO) C.

Comment: @cxw i'm goin got go ahead and say right now that isn't the problem; the two are synonymous in both C and C++ as parameters per the standards, but I can tell you for certain a non-equality condition between `MAXCOL`, the magic value who's definition is conveniently omitted from this source dump, and the value `9` definitely *is* a problem.

Comment: @Pedro - It would be easir to analyze with "matrix.h" included

Comment: what *he* said ========================================^^^^^^

Comment: @WhozCraig - I just remembered - although they are synonymous in the standard, they can differ in implementation.  Somehow I tripped over `int *` and `int []` behaving differently in assembly.  The `int *` had an extra indirection in the generated object code to get to the array contents.  Can't for the life of me remember why I was working at that low a level, but I was, and `int*` vs. `int[]` caused me trouble.

Comment: Please, stackoverflow is not a human debugger.

Comment: @cxw interesting. they're not just synonymous in the standards, they're functional equivalent. C99 §6.7.6.3 for example, "A declaration of a parameter as ‘‘array of type’’ shall be adjusted to ‘‘qualified pointer to type’’" And I definitely think it is a `MAXCOL!=9` issue that sooner or later rears its fugly head.

Comment: Put this at the top of `main()` `printf("%d\n", MAXCOL);` If the value emitted is anything besides `9`, that's likely the problem.

Comment: What are some good debugging tools to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem (the one that's causing your segfault, at least), this happens in several places, both `preMulti()` and `postMulti()`:

```
for( int k = 0; k < row; i++)
```

That should be `k++` at the end, not `i++`.

Comment: That was incredibly silly mistake. Thank you! That was it. I guess I should have just taken a rest and looked at it again. When debugging it wouldn't print the stuff in the inputVector that I wrote for testing. Since the error is in the preMulti and postMulti I don't understand why it would crash before entering that function.

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions:

- Change the array parameters to pointers.  Instead of `int vec[]`, use `int *vec`.  Instead of `int matrix[][MAXCOL]`, use `int **matrix`.  This puts more of the work back on the compiler to manage the memory layout.  If you happen to change the size of the matrix, you will not have to update fixed bounds in all of your prototypes.
- Along the same lines, use `MAXCOL` in the main routine.  `matrix` is declared as `[9][9]`, but does `MAXCOL` actually equal 9?
- Make the main routine and matrix.cpp consistent in their arguments.  `inputVector` is called with either a `row` or `col` number as an argument, but the argument it expects is
  the number of elements in the vector.

Comment: I had MAXCOL there, I was just seeing if it made any difference. With the array parameters, I thought int** was for an pointer to pointers. I'll try it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I did used debugger and I've found the problem is not in your `inputVector` function but here (how else would `inputMatrix` work when analogue `inputVector` would not?):

```
void preMulti(int row, int col, int matrix[][MAXCOL], int vector[],int result[]){
        for(int i = 0; i < col; i++ ) {
            result[i] = 0;
            for( int k = 0; k < row; i++)              // i++ will cause SIGSEGV 
                result[i] += vector[k] * matrix[k][i]; // probably k++ ?
        }
    }
```